# How to code sending an email upon pushing a button on a list view

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a page that displays users based on a view and I would like to add a button to this view that will send off an email that has the subject filled in with the name of the site and some other text.  Maybe even prefill some of the body.

I do not want to create a new field in the list because only a small portion of records will leverage this attribute (only those contacts that have a support role).  The view only displays support role individuals.  I tried to change the existing email link by adding the appropriate information, but I have no clue how to do this.  My next attempt was to add a button and then code behind this button. This has to be only client changes, nothing with master pages.  This is the code I have.  I can call an alert, but not able to put my email string in their to make it work or to call a local js function.  Neither one of these work.

I'm know JS, but I'm no master

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('pageTitle').innerHTML=document.title;
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("buttons");
});

function buttons()
{
    var $t = $('#js-listviewthead-WPQ2').next().next().find('tr');

    $t.each(function(){ 
//     $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' id='btnSub' onclick='alert(document.title);'/>");
    $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' id='btnSub' onclick='<a href="mailto:Steve@Wi.gov?subject=SharePoint Site Support">Steve@wi.gov</a>'>");
  });
}
</script>
```

Email opens up with the subject pre-filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
     addButtons();
});
function addButtons(){
    var listTitle="CustomList";
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' id='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail();'>");
    });
}
function openMail(){
    location.href="mailto:Steve@Wi.gov?subject=SharePoint Site Support";
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, but this will add this to every list on the page.  Is there a way to limit it to only one list.  Specifically, the one that I was trying to do was with the following code:  #js-listviewthead-WPQ2.  Which my code created a button, but could not get the script to run.

Comment: I modified the code, you can modify the listTitle to make it works only one list.